# onItemClickListener() on ViewHolder instead of recylerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing onItemClickListener() on RecyclerView. but it is recommended to do so on viewHolder by implementing View.OnClickListener

here is my code

```
 public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
     ..........
    ............
    private OnItemClickListener onFeedItemClickListener;

     public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
            this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
        }

    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            .........
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                .........
            } else {
                ..........
            }

            holder.btnComments.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.btnComments.setTag(position);
            holder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.btnMore.setTag(position);
}
.........
public static class CellItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        @InjectView(R.id.btnComments)
        ImageButton btnComments;
        @InjectView(R.id.btnMore)
        ImageButton btnMore;

        public CellItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onCommentsClick(View v, int position);
        public void onMoreClick(View v, int position);
    }
```

I am not able to do it in the right way. as i get ether null or no response for my clicks
any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Not really understand what you mean.Can this solve your problem?

```
public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements CellItemViewHolder.OnItemClickListener{

    private Context context;

    public FeedAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        CellItemViewHolder messageRecycleViewHolder = (CellItemViewHolder)viewHolder;
        messageRecycleViewHolder.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public CellItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.main_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new CellItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCommentsClick(View v, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCommentsClick,position:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoreClick(View v, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMoreClick,position:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public static class CellItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    View viewLayout;
    Button moreBtn;
    Button commentBtn;
    OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    int position = 1;

    public CellItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        viewLayout = itemView;

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        moreBtn = (Button)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.more_btn);
        commentBtn = (Button)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);
        moreBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        commentBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public int getMyPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.more_btn:
                if(onItemClickListener != null) {
                    onItemClickListener.onMoreClick(v, getMyPosition());
                }
                break;
            case R.id.comment_btn:
                if(onItemClickListener != null) {
                    onItemClickListener.onCommentsClick(v, getMyPosition());
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onCommentsClick(View v, int position);
        public void onMoreClick(View v, int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me Error:(39, 8) error: cyclic inheritance involving StoryAdapter

Comment: Where is StoryAdapter?